# How to center "header_nav"

Tags: html, css

This is what my header looks like right now at http://www.bolistylus.com

[image]

I am wanting float the nav menu to the right, but when I add `float: right` to the `.header_nav` css it looks like this:

[image]

I still want the top and bottom border to go all the way across header so that's where I'm getting stuck.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="header_nav">
            <div class="head-logo">
                    <h1 id="site-title"><a href="/"><img class="title-image" title="Boli Stylus" src="http://www.bolistylus.com/wp-content/uploads/BoliNewLogo.png" alt="stylus for iPad"/></a></h1>
                    <!--<h2 id="site-description"></h2>-->
            </div>
            <div class="head-nav">
            <ul>

                            <li><a href="/shop">SHOP</a></li>      

                            <!--<li><a href="/products/cosmonaut">BOLI+</a></li>-->


                            <li><a href="/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>

                            <!--<li><a href="/pages/press">PRESS</a></li>-->    

                            <li><a href="/cart">YOUR CART</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
            <br style="clear: both;"/>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.header_nav {
    background: #f3f3f3
    }


.header_nav .head-nav { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }


.header_nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    }

.header_nav ul li a{ 
    padding: 10.5px 21px;
    color: #000000;
    }

.header_nav ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #a8cb17;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:right` in `.header_nav .head-nav` as this will wrap the content to the width of the children. Use `text-align: right` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:100%;` to .header_nav .head-nav

and add `float:right;` to .header_nav ul li

Edit: I live edited this on your site via FireBug and it gave the result you were looking for. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to float the image to the right too:

```
.head-logo img
{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the `float:right` to .header_nav ul.

```
.header_nav {
    background: #f3f3f3
}

.header_nav .head-nav { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.header_nav ul{
    float: right;
}

.header_nav ul li{
    display: inline;
}

.header_nav ul li a{ 
    padding: 10.5px 21px;
    color: #000000;
}

.header_nav ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #a8cb17;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Output](http://jsfiddle.net/3YgZ7/1/) (**UPDATED**)

Comment: @novicePrgrmr That's easy to fix, just add `<br style="clear: both;"/>` immediately after the closing `</ul>` tag. I've updated the JSFiddle link with the change.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.header_nav {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%; /* not-needed? */
    }


.header_nav .head-nav { 
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to float your list items instead of the whole container, try this:

```
.head-nav:before, .head-nav:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}

.head-nav:after {
    clear: both;
}

.head-nav ul {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ftps/

you need to add the float to the ul see example.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div class="head-nav" align=right>
```

will solve your issue

cheers